# Getting 'No_Oauth_Code' Exception while logging to salesforce using FB credentials

Tags: apex, integration, facebook

My Apex class(RegistrationHandler) :

```
global class ForNagAutoHandler implements Auth.RegistrationHandler{
    global User createUser(Id portalId, Auth.UserData data) {
        User u = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Email = :data.Email];
        return u;
    }

    global void updateUser(Id userId, Id portalId, Auth.UserData data) {



    }
}
```

The error url im getting is :

```
https://ap1.salesforce.com/_nc_external/identity/sso/ui/AuthorizationError?ErrorCode=No_Oauth_Code&ErrorDescription=Exchange+code+was+not+returned#_=_
```

Any idea pals

Answer (score 4):

This happens when you've the Sandbox mode turned on for your FB app.

1) Open https://developers.facebook.com/

2) Select your app from top navigation bar (Apps)

3) Click on Status & Review (Left Sidebar)

4) You will find a toggle button to do on/off your app from sandbox mode. By default it will on for sandbox mode if you are creating new app.

[image]

This should fix it!